# How to change from SQLite to MySQL in remix.js?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, remix

I'm currently building my website using 'remix-run / indie-stack' (https://github.com/remix-run/indie-stack), and I have trouble about converting query language from sqlite to MySQL. I've already changed various files to MySQL syntax, including: migration.sql, schema.prisma, and migration_lock.toml.

Also, I'm using Google Cloud SQL for my database. But, system prints out application error while accessing the database. I think it happens because some parts are not properly changed to MySQL syntax.

So what parts shall I should consider to successfully change my syntax to MySQL?